# How to create a menu programmatically in Android?

Tags: android, xml, layout, menu

Now I want to add it a menu on the bottom of the screen.
I wrote a lot of about but still didnt get how to do that.
My main problem is that I dont have an xml file on my main page.
its look liks that:

```
   public class start  extends ListActivity {
        static final String[] COUNTRIES = new String[] {
        "NEWS1", "NEWS2","RADIO"};
 Intent intent;
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

      setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, COUNTRIES));

      ListView lv = getListView();
      lv.setTextFilterEnabled(true);

      lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
            int position, long id) {
if (((TextView) view).getText().equals("NEWS1")){
 intent = new Intent(start.this,  NewsActivity.class);
```

how can I add a menu with an action.
please give me a example.
thanks

Comment: Tab-Menu or the Menu as in when you press the Menu-button on the phone?

Comment: Menu-button on the phone

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ya its fine if you dont have an XML file in your main activity. You can still add menu to it by following this steps ->

1. create an android XML file and select menu as type(It will get stored under res folder's menu sub folder).
2. Now in your main activity code add this two methods ->

   ```java
   public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu){
       getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.yourmenuxmlfilename, menu);
       return true;
   }
   public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item){
       switch(item.getItemId){
           case R.id.item1:
               // what you want to do with first button
               break;
           case .....
               break;
       }
       return true;
   }
   ```

Comment: this method onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) from where I need to call it(from what method to call it?)??? and how to add items to menu?

Comment: simply add this method to your start class but remember that dont add this method within your onCreate() method, add them separately. And go to menu XML file to add items to it. It is very simple.

Comment: thanks work but the items are black i cant see them on the black font on a black ground

Comment: If my answer helped you please upvote my answer. And regarding blackbackground you can add icon to the items so that you can see them

Answer (score 38):

use this code to add menu dynamically

```
private static final int NEW_MENU_ID=Menu.FIRST+1;

@Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);

        menu.add(0, NEW_MENU_ID, 0, "New"); 

        return true;
    }
```

Comment: What use is the `public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu)` method here? Removing it does not show any difference.

Answer (score 1):

For a context menu you just add

```
            getListView().setOnCreateContextMenuListener(new OnCreateContextMenuListener() {

                @Override
                public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v,
                        ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {

                    menu.setHeaderTitle("Options");
                    menu.add("Option1");
                    menu.add("Option2");
                    menu.add("Option3");

                }
            });
```

The context menu just appears on long click to the list item

Answer (score -1):

For options menu

create an android xml file that you inflate in options menu

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

    new MenuInflater(this).inflate(R.layout.options, menu);
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    //and your action for menu item click goes here
```